# How to properly implement MoralisDappProvider as a React component?

Tags: reactjs, moralis

There's some code in the documention of Moralis and at github, but it no longer works.

For instance:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState, useMemo } from "react";
import { useMoralis } from "react-moralis";
import MoralisDappContext from "./context";

function MoralisDappProvider({ children }) {
  const { Moralis, user, web3, enableWeb3, isWeb3Enabled } = useMoralis();
  // const web3Provider = /*await*/ Moralis.enableWeb3();  //needed at all?


  useEffect(() => {
    Moralis.onChainChanged(function (chain) {
      setChainId(chain);
    });

    Moralis.onAccountChanged(function (address) {
      setWalletAddress(address[0]);
    });
    // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
  }, []);


  // doesn't work
  useEffect(() => setChainId(web3.givenProvider?.chainId)); // "givenProvider" doesn't exist


  //.....
```

Not to mention that there's no code as a whole, but there're only pieces of code: one here, other there.... and some don't work. How to glue them, after all?

The `givenProvider?` property doesn't even exist.

Is there code that works?

How to, generally, properly implement `MoralisDappProvider` component?